# NSString * to Char[] (GameCenter Send Struct)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, game-center

I want to send a `struct` to another player in GameCenter. 
I have read the other questions about this, however, I cannot get any of them to work.

I need to get `@"1234"` into a `char[4]`  (ex char[0] = '1', char[1] = '2', etc)

I have tried `[NSString UTF8String]`, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

It assigns fine, but when I pull it back into `NSString *` with `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]`, It returns blank.

If someone could show me the conversion to and from, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I can't get it to work :/ Here is my code (the abridged version):

**Matchmaker.h**

```
enum { NChars = 4 };

typedef struct {
    MessageType messageType;
} Message;

typedef struct {
    Message message;
    char code[NChars];
} MessageGameCode;

@interface Matchmaker : CCLayer <GameCenterMasterDelegate>{

    NSString *_code;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *_code;
```

**Matchmaker.m**

```
@synthesize _code;
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self._code = @"1234";
}

- (void)sendCode {
    NSLog(@"Sending Code....");
    MessageGameCode message;
    message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeGameCode;
    NSString * const source = self._code;

    const char* const sourceAsUTF8 = source.UTF8String;

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NChars; ++idx) {
        message.code[idx] = sourceAsUTF8[idx];
    }
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:NChars];    
    [self sendData:data];
}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {
    Message *message = (Message *) [data bytes];
    if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeGameCode) {        

        MessageGameCode *codeMessage = (MessageGameCode *)[data bytes];
        self._code = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:codeMessage->code length:NChars encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self setGameState:kGameStateWaitingForStart];
        NSLog(@"Game Code Recieved");
        NSLog(@"Recieved Code: %@",self._code); //This always shows self._code as blank

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt will fail because the cstring which you pass to `+ [NSString stringWithUTF8String:]` is not terminated.

Try this:

```
NSString * result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes
                                             length:4
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Edit**

A more complete demonstration:

```
enum { NChars = 4 };
/* requires error checking */
void transmit() {
    NSString * const source = @"1234";

    char tmp[NChars] = { 0 };
    const char* const sourceAsUTF8 = source.UTF8String;

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NChars; ++idx) {
      tmp[idx] = sourceAsUTF8[idx];
    }
    /* .. */
}

/* requires error checking */
void receive(const char bytes[NChars]) {
    NSString * result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:NChars encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: well, the result of `-UTF8String` is terminated, but if he's copying it into a buffer without allowing space for termination, that's going to be a problem.

Comment: @DavidGelhar exactly (+1). although that *is* the buffer I specified in my original answer, i've added a more complete demonstration for clarification.

Comment: I still can't quite get it to work. I think I'm missing something super obvious. I edited my post with my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios a problem in your example is that what is sent and what the receiver expects are two different sizes. only part of the MessageGameCode is sent. to send the whole message by copy, use `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)];`

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
char bytes[4];

NSData* data = [@"1234" dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([data length] <= 4)
{
    memcpy(bytes, [data bytes], [data length]);
}
```

And to go the other way:

```
NSString* recodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: bytes 
                                                   length: savedLengthFromBefore 
                                                 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possible pitfalls here.

One is that with `[NSString UTF8String]` ["The returned C string is automatically freed just as a returned object would be released; you should copy the C string if it needs to store it outside of the autorelease context in which the C string is created."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). So, depending on how long you're expecting the value to stick around you may need to copy it (for example, using `strcpy`)

The other issue is that `[NSString UTF8String]` and `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]` both expect NULL-terminated C strings, so you need a char[5], not a char[4] to hold @"1234".